# Make tesseract recognise numbers only

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to refine an OCR prog I made to read the layout of a certain image that I am using. Right now, I would like my OCR prog to recognise only digits 0-9.

I tried to follow the solution from the question:

[Limit characters tesseract is looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363490/limit-characters-tesseract-is-looking-for)

But I got stuck in the part where I have to call tesseract as:

```
tesseract input.tif output nobatch letters
```

where does this go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I posted some things about tesseract some time ago in SO: see [Tesseract OCR Library - Learning Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908919/tesseract-ocr-library-learning-font/4931336#4931336). There is notably a [link to tesseract training](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) which will tell you how to restrain your set of characters and describe your ambiguities.

Answer (score 8):

i had the same issue using python, wit tesseract 3
Assuming further readers may do so.

from here : https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-recognize-only-digits

and here:
https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/27fed535bf1eb665ec991313841b177336b50f61/src/pytesseract.py#L91

i succeeded using :

> pytesseract.image_to_string(someimage, config='outputbase digits')

Answer (score 4):

This question is answered on [Tesseract FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_recognize_only_digits?)

And here is how you can get tesseract to recognise numbers only:

Tesseract 2 - BEFORE calling an Init function or put this in a text file called tessdata/configs/digits:

```
tessedit_char_whitelist 0123456789
```

and then your command line becomes:

```
tesseract image.tif outputbase nobatch digits
```

Tesseract 3 - A digits config file is already created, so just run a tesseract command like this:

```
tesseract imagename outputbase digits
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the command you use to tesseract run on command line.

For a better answer, we need to know if you are running tesseract on command line or as a library.