# Tesseract-OCR not recognizing digits

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, division

I using Tesseract OCR to recognizing my below picture (it is an image meter electric) but it not working. ***I have not permitted to use Machine learning or deep learning.*** Does anyone have some other technique that I can use to solve my problem? please let give to me a guide.  Thank you for reading.

**This my root image:**
[image]

**This image that I have processed must to recognizing digits**
[image]

**This my code:**

```
import cv2
import pytesseract as pts
pts.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\Thep Ho\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread("images/text1.jpg")
text = pts.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

Comment: Did you already check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574142/pytesseract-using-tesseract-4-0-numbers-only-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304286/make-tesseract-recognise-numbers-only/19787319) ?

Answer (score 0):

- If you apply `adaptive-thresholding` to the input image:

---

- [image]
- Now, if you apply `regular-expression` to remove all non-numeric variables from the extracted text:

  - ```sh
    99951
    ```

Code:

---

```py
import re
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("Eadxj.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
flt = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry,
                            252, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 31, 7)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(flt)
txt_int = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", txt)
print(txt_int)
```

But if you are allowed to use `deep-learning`, result will be:

[image]